# How do you draw a custom widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I created a Zone class for my "game", which are rectangles with colors parameters (and probably events in the future).

I created a new file, zone.dart, with 2 classes, a statelesswidget extension and a custompainter extension to draw it. I also called the constructor from main.dart, it successfully compiles but does not output anything. For debug, I have set a fixed color and size in zone.dart.

```
main.dart (basic)
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Zone(Colors.red),
          new Zone(Colors.blue),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}


zone.dart
class Zone extends StatelessWidget {

  final Color color;

  Zone(this.color);

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new CustomPaint(
      painter: new ZonePainter(color),
    );
  }

}



class ZonePainter extends CustomPainter {

  final Color color;

  ZonePainter(this.color);

  @override 
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(
      new Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 400, 400),
      new Paint()..color = new Color(0xFF0000),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(ZonePainter oldDelegate) => color != oldDelegate.color;

}
```

I think it should have drawn the rectangles assuming there are no errors. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListView` children don't have intrinsic [box constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints) by default, so the `Zone` widget doesn't know what size it should be. The `drawRect` in the `CustomPainter` does not enforce this.

Wrap your `Zone` widget in a `Container` with a fixed height, or any other widget that enforces constraints, and the ListView will show it properly. Adding a child to the `CustomPaint` does this as well.

For example:

```dart
...
ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      child: new Zone(Colors.red),
      height: 100,
    ),
    new Zone(Colors.blue),
  ],
),
...
```

or

```dart
CustomPaint(
  painter: new ZonePainter(color),
  child: Container(
    height: 100,
  ),
);
```

PS: the color `Color(0xFF0000)` is incorrect and should be `Color(0xFF000000)` for full black, but I think you meant to add `this.color` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The color is the problem, in the painter you're using a fixed color code (also the hex is incomplete). You have to use the color from the constructor

you have: `new Paint()..color = new Color(0xFF0000),`

you should have: `new Paint()..color = color,`